# Regex get the string value in between \n's in various situations

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the Test Data1's value

Currently have..

```
(?<=(?i)Test Data1)(.*)[^|\n]+
(?<=(?i)Test Data1)[)?]*[^\n]+
(?<=(?i)Test Data1)[\s:?](.*)[^\n]+
```

Case #1.
\nTest Data1: {1, 2, 3}\nTest Data2: {4, 5, 6}\n

Case #2.
\nTest Data1 {1, 2, 3}\nTest Data2 {4, 5, 6}\n

Case #3.
\nTest Data1:\n{1, 2, 3}\nTest Data2: {4, 5, 6}\n

Case #4.
\nTest Data1\n{1, 2, 3}\nTest Data2 {4, 5, 6}\n

Current regex I have returns case #1 and #2 fine, but since case#3 and case#4 have an extra \n before {1, 2, 3}, my regex just fails.

Is there a better/improved regex that I can always only get the Test Data1's value {1, 2, 3} in those 4 situations above?

Answer (score 0):

In case #4 you have

```
(?<=(?i)Test Data1)[\s:?](.*)[^\n]+
```

Is your intent that there be an optional whitespace or colon after `Test Data1`?  That would be

```
[\s:]?
```

but you have

```
[\s:?]
```

which means "whitespace or colon or a question mark", and it's not optional.

Comment: Ahh good catch! Thank you so much! Quick question before I accept the answer. I'm using the [^\n]+ at the end because I want anything until the \n.

Comment: Is it okay for it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/kDc9Eg/1) the result you wanted

```
Test Data1:?\n?\s?(\{\d+,\s+\d+,\s+\d+\})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
(?i)Test Data1[\s:]*\K.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ymvBB/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching ON
- `Test Data1` - a literal text
- `[\s:]*` - zero or more whitespaces and `:` chars
- `\K` - omit all text matched so far
- `.*` - match the current line till end (`.` matches any char but line break chars)

Depending on regex flavor, you can also use

```
(?i)Test Data1[\s:]*\K.*
(?i)(?<=Test Data1[\s:]*).*
(?i)Test Data1[\s:]*(.*)
```